# How to get multiple variables set from one String in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, variables, split

I am attempting to get multiple String variables set with one println. Here is what I have:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

String teacher = "";
String classSelect = "";
String location = "";

System.out.println("Enter a teacher: ");
teacher = scanner.next();

System.out.println("Enter a class name: ");
classSelect = scanner.next();

System.out.println("Enter a location: ");
location = scanner.next();
```

Here is what I would like to accomplish:

```
String section = "";
String instructor = "";
String location = "";

System.out.printf("Only fill in applicable criteria, leave the rest blank :\n"
        + "Section://Sets section var// \n"
        + "Instructor://Sets instructor var// \n"
        + "Location://Sets location var// \n");
```

Comment: You can do this but it would be far, far more complicated than what you have now.  When you develop GUIs would will find that work completely differently.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I cant wait to get to the GUI, but I am required to build it via command line first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be an ethical way but try it

```
System.out.printf("Only fill in applicable criteria, leave the rest blank and use | after every field:\n"
        + "Section://Sets section var// \n"
        + "Instructor://Sets instructor var// \n"
        + "Location://Sets location var// \n");
```

if the user enteres

```
abc|xyz|loc
```

accept it in a string

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
String[] inputs=input.split("|");
inputs[0]//<--section
inputs[1]//<--instructor
inputs[2]//<--location
```

Comment: you can use space as a split character also :)

Comment: Thats given me something to go and refine, thanks @Bhavik Shah for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
   String message = 
        String.format("Only fill in applicable criteria, leave the rest blank :\n"
        + "Section: %s \n"
        + "Instructor: %s \n"
        + "Location:%s \n", 
        section ,instructor,location );
```

or this?

```
    System.out.printf("Only fill in applicable criteria, leave the rest blank :\n"
            + "Section: %s \n"
            + "Instructor: %s \n"
            + "Location:%s \n", 
            section ,instructor,location );
```

Comment: As far as I know that would just print what those variables contain, not allow me to set them.